# Giving error when using Linq query to delete multiple rows

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

This is what I am trying to delete multiple rows in linq mvc 4.

```
int perm_id = (from c in db.tm_perm_level where c.perm_levelname == perm_name select c.perm_id).FirstOrDefault();
tblpermission objperm=(from c in db.tblpermission.Where (c.perm_id==perm_id) select c);

db.tblpermission.Remove(objperm);
int rowiseffected = db.SaveChanges();
```

Near where I am getting error. This is data in table

```
id  s.id   perm_id  read  write
3   1        1      True    True
4   2        1      True    True
23  1        2      True    False
24  1        2      True    False
```

This is linq code I tried

```
var objperm = (from c in db.ts_perm_levelmapping where (c.perm_id == perm_id) select c);
            foreach(var item in objperm)
            {
                db.ts_perm_levelmapping.Remove(item);
                int rowiseffected = db.SaveChanges();

            }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: the best overloaded method match for system.data.entity.dbset(mvc1.tblpermiisiion) .remove has some invalid arguments

Comment: Can u suggest me where I am going wrong?

Comment: `.Remove()` takes a single object (not a collection) - `tblpermission objperm = db.tblpermission.Where(d=>d.perm_id==perm_id).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: if I want to remove multiple enties at same time then which method I should follow?

Comment: Then use `RemoveRange()` (EF6 or higher)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is typo error. you are using two type of linq syntax.. 
 use this

```
  var objperm=(from c in db.tblpermission where (c.perm_id==perm_id) select c);
```

or use this

```
  var objperm=db.tblpermission.Where(d=>d.perm_id==perm_id);
```

for deleting all the objects you can use `RemoveRange` if you are using **EntityFramework 6**

```
   db.tblpermission.RemoveRange(objperm);
```

if not then you can use iteration

like

```
   foreach(var a in objperm)  
   {
    db.tblpermission.Remove(a);
   }
```

or other option will be [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended)

Comment: I tried above now in below line I am getting error   db.tblpermission.Remove(objperm);

Comment: the best overloaded method match for system.data.entity.dbset(mvc1.tblpermiisiion) .remove has some invalid arguments

Comment: delete once at a while ... itterate the 'objperm' and the remove it.

Comment: yes I thought same login but how to iterate object inside the query. First time I am doing this

Comment: Now this error i am getting an error occurred while starting a connection on the provider connection. Updated code above I mentioned.

Comment: keep 'db.SaveChanges()' out of the loop .

Comment: Working fine thank you lot. This is very usefull concept